# What are non-held-out data or non-held-out classes?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, terminology, cross-validation

I'm Spanish and I don't understand the meaning of "non-held-out". I have tried Google Translator and online dictionaries like Longman but I can't find a suitable translation for this term.

You can find these term using this [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&biw=1920&bih=901&ei=WUe6XtOICaqIlwTQ8Yy4BA&q=%22non-held-out%22%20meaning&oq=%22non-held-out%22%20meaning&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQDFAAWABghCBoAHAAeACAAQCIAQCSAQCYAQCqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiTmcCZ3q3pAhUqxIUKHdA4A0c4ChDh1QMICw), and in articles like this one:

1. "**computing SVD on the non-held-out data**" from [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10618-019-00616-4).
2. "**The training set consists all the images and annotations containing non-held-out classes while held-out classes are masked as background during the training**" from [Few-Shot Semantic Segmentation with Prototype Learning](http://bmvc2018.org/contents/papers/0255.pdf).
3. "**A cross-validation procedure is that non held out data (meaning after holding out the test set) is splitted in k folds/sets**" from [here](https://datasciencelab.its.uconn.edu/cross-validation/).

What is non-held-out data and held-out data or classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Held-out simply means "not included" particularly in the sense of:

**This part of the data was not included in this specific training run.**

Depending on the context of all of these text **non-held-out data/classes means the data that actually was included in a particular modeling exercise.**

Consider this excerpt from your first example:

> For instance, Owen and Perry (2009) show a method for **holding out data**, computing SVD on the **non-held-out data**, and selecting k so as to minimize the reconstruction error between the **held-out data** and its SVD approximation.

It actually means:

> For instance, Owen and Perry (2009) show a method for **excluding data**, computing SVD on the **remaining data**, and selecting k so as to minimize the reconstruction error between the **excluded data** and its SVD approximation.

So it simply talks about a particular way of train-test-validation splitting the data.